# Использование функции DATE_FORMAT в запросе

Tags: mysql, функции, запрос, дата, форматирование

У меня есть запрос:

```
SELECT `news_id`, `title`, `date` FROM `news`
```

В БД MySQL дата хранится в виде 2016-01-22 18:44:03, тип поля: `date`;
Подскажите как и где прописать функцию - `DATE_FORMAT(" ",'%d.%m.%Y')`, чтобы получить при выводе полученной даты значение например - 22.01.2016?

Comment: У вас колонка date объявлена как строка, т.е. какой нибудь varchar, или все таки как date, как ей и положено быть. Потому как если она типа date то просто `SELECT news_id, title,  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y') FROM news`. И в вопросах всегда указывайте какую именно СУБД вы используете. Сейчас можно догадаться что mysql, потому как функции date_format в других базах просто нет, но мало ли ...

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Mike да это mysql и у date тип дата.
Запрос работает, он возвращает в массив элемент с ключём [DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y')] и нужным мне значением. 
Но как сделать чтобы ключ этот был просто [date]?

Comment: @Tombland используйте директиву AS. Т.е. `DATE_FORMAT(...) AS news_date` даст вам в массиве индекс `news_date`

Comment: newman и Mike спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, использовать [CONVERT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp), чтобы преобразовать дату в строку формата `dd.mm.yyyy`:

```sql
SELECT news_id, title, CONVERT(varchar,date,104) AS date FROM news
```

Другой вариант - преобразовать сначала в date формат (если его понимает используемая БД)

```sql
SELECT news_id, title, CONVERT(date,date) AS date FROM news
```

а преобразование 2016-01-22 в 22.01.2016 можно отложить до программы клиента (JavaScript, например). Последний вариант позволяет передавать информацию между сервером и клиентом в формате, независимом от языка и страны, и показывать результат, в конце концов, в формате используемом клиентом. Но если речь идет о простой программе, то первый вариант - наиболее просой.

Comment: Вы видимо ясновидец, раз предположили, что используется ms sql server, ибо convert в приведенном вами виде - это именно его функция. А автор вопроса спросил про date_format, которая является функцией mysql.

Comment: @Mike: Ясновидец - знает или видит, а мне приходится только гадать. Фраза "хранится в виде" может означать все, что угодно. В этом я с Вами согласен. Если спрашивающий слышал о функции `DATE_FORMAT`, но не знает где ее "прописать", то вообще возжожно, что он работает с любой произвольной БД, а не с MySQL, как Вы предполагаете.

Comment: Работаю с MySQL. Извиняюсь за неполную информацию в вопросе

Comment: @Tombland: OK, Просто имейте ввиду на будующее. И еще, настоятельно рекомендую использовать правильные тэги вопроса. Например, на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql можно смотреть все (но не ваш) MySQL вопросы, можно подписаться по тэгу и т.п. Используя правильный тэг вы резко повышаете вероятность того, что специалисты по интересующей Вас теме увидят вопрос и помогут Вам.

Comment: @Oleg понял спасибо за совет